# PDFSharp adding digital Signature to PDF not working PdfSignatureField

Tags: digital-signature, pdfsharp

I am using PDFsharp-extended version 1.0.1 and have the following code

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
 using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.AcroForms;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.Security;

class Program
{
 static void Main()
  {
    string inputPdfPath = "input.pdf";
    string outputPdfPath = "output.pdf";
    string privateKeyPath = "privatekey.pfx";
    string privateKeyPassword = "password";


    PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(inputPdfPath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);


    PdfSignatureField signatureField = new PdfSignatureField(document.Pages[0], "Signature");
    signatureField.SignatureHandler = new X509Certificate2SignatureHandler(privateKeyPath,     privateKeyPassword);


    document.AcroForm.Fields.Add(signatureField);

    document.Save(outputPdfPath);

    Console.WriteLine("PDF signed successfully.");
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error CS1729  'PdfSignatureField' does not contain a constructor that
> takes 2 arguments

I have tried with multiple inputs but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that version of PDFsharp only uses 1 parameter for the c'tor.

Your sample code comes from a different source and does not match the port of the library you are using.